# Android Tests GitHub Actions: no such file or directory, open 'undefined/licenses/android-sdk-arm-dbt-license'

Tags: android, flutter, github-actions

We are trying to test the Android version of a flutter/dart app via GitHub Actions.

The GitHub actions file looks like this:

```
android_integration:
    name: Integration Tests on Android Devices
    runs-on: self-hosted
    strategy:
      matrix:
        api-level: [30]
        target: [google_apis]
    steps:
      - name: Use Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1

      - name: Android Home Variables
        run: |
          echo "~/Library/Android/sdk" >> $GITHUB_PATH
          echo "~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools" >> $GITHUB_PATH
          echo "~/Library/Android/sdk/tools" >> $GITHUB_PATH
          echo "~/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH

      - name: Run Flutter Driver tests
        uses: reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2
        env:
          ANDROID_HOME: ~/Library/Android/sdk
        with:
          api-level: ${{ matrix.api-level }}
          target: ${{ matrix.target }}
          arch: x86_64
          script: firebase emulators:exec "./flutter_drive_android.sh"
```

The "./flutter_drive_android.sh" script that is run looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
 
flutter drive --disable-service-auth-codes --target=test_driver/app.dart --flavor=production -d emulator-5554
```

This script works fine when run directly locally, but when run through GitHub Actions this is the output:

```
API level: 30
target: google_apis
CPU architecture: x86_64
Hardware profile: 
SD card path or size: 
AVD name: test
emulator options: -no-window -gpu swiftshader_indirect -no-snapshot -noaudio -no-boot-anim
disable animations: true
Script:
firebase emulators:exec "./flutter_drive_android.sh"
Installing new cmdline-tools.
/usr/bin/unzip -q ~/workspace/actions-runner/_work/_temp/861ba3fb-c25d-4258-9886-b3c24ac0b4ba
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill
error: could not connect to TCP port 5554: Connection refused
The process '~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' failed with exit code 1
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'undefined/licenses/android-sdk-arm-dbt-license'
```

I can't tell where the "undefined is coming from on the last line, 'undefined/licenses/android-sdk-arm-dbt-license'. It seems possible that it is related to the "Connection refused" error, but I can't tell why that is happening either.

Any help would be appreciated.